# SOLR - How do I pull field values from documents when adding them to SOLR?

Tags: solr

Using SolrJ with SOLR 1.4.1.

So I have a set of fields defined which I want to index on.  Say I have a body of hundreds of documents (assume they're text files), which I want to add to SOLR to create indices for.  Is there a way for me to feed SOLR the documents and have it find the fields' values in each of those documents?

For example, suppose I have a field in the SOLR schema called "manufacturer".  I also have a document with the text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
>   dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
>   veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
>   ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
>   commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
>   dolor  **manufacturer acme** in reprehenderit in voluptate
>   velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
>   nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
>   occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
>   in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
>   anim id est laborum.

Can I somehow get SOLR to pluck "acme" out of that document as the value for the field "manufacturer"?  Or, do I need to manually go through each document before adding it into SOLR and manually find the values for each field with something like:

```
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField("manufacturer", "acme");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do that in Solr. You have a couple of options:

- Build Solr JSON/XML input documents by hand
- Use natural language processing to annotate your documents and then use the annotations to generate individual Solr fields (see [Solr UIMA](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrUIMA))
- Write your own [UpdateRequestProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor) that pulls the fields out of your documents via regular expressions, XPaths or whatever works for you